# Show UTF-8 text properly in Gradle

Tags: text, utf-8, build, gradle

I have a task:

```
task info<<{
    println "Gradle — система автоматической сборки, построенная на принципах Apache Ant и Apache Maven, но предоставляющая DSL на языке Groovy вместо традиционной XML-образной формы представления конфигурации проекта."
}
```

when I use the command:

```
gradle info -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

The text is not shown properly. How to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `file.encoding` system property needs to be set right when the JVM executing the Gradle build (e.g. the Gradle Daemon) starts up. One way to achieve this is with `export GRADLE_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=utf-8"`. Another way that might work is to add `systemProp.file.encoding=utf-8` to `gradle.properties`. Of course this assumes that the build script files are actually using utf-8 encoding. To see what your platform's (and therefore Gradle's) default encoding is, print out the system property's value in a build script.

Comment: My System file.encoding=Cp1251. So if I change it on my machine to UTF-8 will this solve my problem in general?

Comment: What matters is the *Java platform encoding*.

Comment: OK .I add System Environment Variable on my machine:
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS to -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Then when start gradle task info
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Gradle ╨▓╨ВтАЭ ╨б╨Г╨а╤С╨б╨Г╨бтАЪ╨а┬╡╨а╤Ш╨а┬░ ╨а┬░╨а╨Ж╨бтАЪ╨а╤Х╨а╤Ш╨а┬░╨бтАЪ╨а╤С╨бтАб╨а┬╡╨б╨Г╨а╤Ф╨а╤Х╨атДЦ ╨б╨Г╨а┬▒╨а╤Х╨б╨В╨а╤Ф╨а╤С,
Where I do something wrong?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Gradle task info picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS". Try to set `GRADLE_OPTS` (on Windows you may need to open a new command prompt after that), make sure to stop the daemon once (`gradle --stop`), and edit the file to force its recompilation. If that doesn't help, chances are that your file isn't utf-8.

Comment: Adding `systemProp.file.encoding=utf-8` to `gradle.properties` doesn't work. `GRADLE_OPTS` works.

Comment: Shouldn't be it sysProp.file.encoding=utf-8 rather than systemProp...? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties

Comment: I'm having similar problems, and been trying to resolve with the suggestions given here (running on Windows). I've verified that my file.encoding is set to utf-8 ('println System.getProperty("file.encoding")), but still can't output special characters correctly. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: @rwalker, are you sure that both steps reside within the same Jenkins node? (one being the code part where you write file.encoding to console and the other being the code part where your special character outputting actually fails)

Comment: @tapa-save answer solved the problem from the project settings which is best for me

Answer (score 100):

I use next setting in `build.gradle` and it works fine for me:

```
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Comment: I believe that iterating over all JavaCompile task will also set the encoding the compileJava task. Thus, you don't need the first line in your snippet.

Comment: not working for me, I think here is not the last one for encoding set, this has been overwritten later I think

Comment: Intellij settings, compiler options didn't work for me, this did.

Answer (score 35):

In gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs='-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8'
```

Comment: Thank you, burned an hour on this.
This was the only thing that worked for running JUnit tests in a Gradle project in IDEA.

Even "systemProp.file.encoding=utf-8" in gradle.properties didn't do it oddly enough.

Comment: It seems that `gradle.properties` is not generated, at least since Gradle 7.6.

Answer (score 14):

if you're using kotlin DSL, then:

build.gradle.kts:

```
tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For my only works with this in build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
....
test {
    systemProperty "file.encoding", "utf-8"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution is to wrap gradle build call into the sh script and export encoding settings in this script:
**buildScript.sh:**

```
export GRADLE_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=utf-8" 
gradlew clean build ...
```

P.S. this solution has been successfully checked and provided

Comment: Don't wrap the Gradle build. Use the gradle.properties to configure the file encoding. Done. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44742865/960875

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I wrote Chinese in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`, and then I added `systemProp.file.encoding=utf-8` and `export GRADLE_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=utf -8"` does not take effect.

I think the reason may be that before loading these things, `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` has been loaded in the default encoding.

My final solution is to convert Chinese to Unicode, such as `\u6211\u7684\u8d44\u6e90` and then write `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

All solution above need changes to IDE settings and IDE restart.

I managed to solve this problem by adding some lines to build.gradle

```
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

test {
    systemProperty "file.encoding", "utf-8"
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```