# Build using Grails application using Gradle using wrong encoding in GSP

Tags: grails, gradle

I have a Grails application and when building the WAR via a Gradle build script, the views are rendered with the wrong encoding (i.e. French characters are showing incorrectly).

When running the application or building directly from grails, everything renders correctly.

So, to be specific:

Grails - `grails war` works correctly

Gradle - `gradle grails-war -PgrailsEnv=prod` gives incorrect encoding.

build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
        maven  {
            url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:2.1.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'grails'

version = 1.0

grails {
    grailsVersion = '2.4.3'
    groovyVersion = '2.4.3' 
}

repositories {
    jcenter {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }   
    grails.central()
}

dependencies {
    bootstrap 'org.grails.plugins:tomcat:7.0.50'
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache:1.1.7"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:rest:0.8"
    runtime ("org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:4.3.5.5") {
        exclude module: 'xml-apis'
    }
    runtime "org.grails.plugins:database-migration:1.4.0"

    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [mr.haki's post about Gradle encoding](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2012/06/gradle-goodness-set-java-compiler.html) or [answers for similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267234/show-utf-8-text-properly-in-gradle):

> To set the encoding property on all compile tasks in our project we
>   can use the withType() method on the TaskContainer to find all tasks
>   of type Compile. Then we can set the encoding in the configuration
>   closure:
>
> ```
> compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
>
> tasks.withType(Compile) {
>     options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
> }
> ```

Look also on [section Environments in official docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/conf.html#environments).

Comment: I did review these references already, and re-visited them following your comment. Unfortunately, I continue to have troubles. I posted a comment on thta question you referenced, since my issue does seem to related. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with HTML templates.

Adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` as JVM parameter for the gradle build fixed the problem for the templates.

For the `*.gsp` files you can add

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
```

to the `<head>` section of your file.