# incorrect console output in different projects at same machine

Tags: java, intellij-idea, utf-8, console

I've spent almost 3 days to find out why in a big project the output of

```
System.out.println( "你好" );
```

is shown as "??"
and in another project built-from-scratch it is shown as "你好".

I am using IntellijIdea, BUT the same thing happens to me while running it from a jar-file using

```
java -jar ...
```

The only two differences between those 2 project is in build system: first one uses gradle and second one uses none (just a simple project). The second difference is about output of the following code

```
     System.out.println("Charset.defaultCharset=" + 
     Charset.defaultCharset());
```

The first one types "Charset.defaultCharset=windows-1252", second one "Charset.defaultCharset=UTF-8"

Well, I HAVE read about:

1. the encoding in IntellijIdea, all settings between 2 projects are the same
   (Settings → File Encoding → Project Encoding → IDE Encoding)
2. About the encoding of file setting in the right lower corner in Idea
3. Tried 
   -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 and then
   -Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8 in debug configurations for all gradle instances
4. in cmd console did

   ```
   set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dconsole.encoding=UTF8

   set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
   ```
5. Played with gradle properties in gradle.build

   ```
   org.gradle.jvmargs='-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8'
   systemProp.file.encoding=UTF-8
   ```
6. changed the the coding in command prompt via

   ```
   chcp  65001
   ```

Those efforts bring me to nothing. Any ideas ?

BTW THERE IS almost the same question but with no answer. I cannot write there cause of low reputation
[Intellij Idea incorrect encoding in console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231291/intellij-idea-incorrect-encoding-in-console-output)

[the picture with settings in project that don't correctly display the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2Gi8.png)

Comment: have you seen this ?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267234/show-utf-8-text-properly-in-gradle

Comment: Yes, I've tried compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
} with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally i've got it!

Navigate to help -> edit custom vm options...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ5JM.jpg)

Add those ones:

-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8

Restart idea completely.

Comment: Well, optionally we can add following code  in gradlew.bat                                                                              @rem Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and GRADLE_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8      either

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have done most of what i thought of 1...5 if the issue still persist, try restarting the ide or the machine.

Try that and let see...

Comment: well, it's not only me, but others people meet such problems with that project. But It's me who have to fix that issue ;-)

Comment: You have done all the  five step, but no outcome? Could check the encoding in IntellijIdea, (Settings → File Encoding → Project Encoding → IDE Encoding) to see if the encoding has changed to UTF-8

Comment: no luck, yep.   the output of Charset.defaultCharset()); is embarassing me, I think I should go in this way...

Comment: I've added the picture (actually a link) that shows the encoding in Idea

Comment: So you restart the ide yet?

Comment: Tried again right now. It gave me errors about Could not get unknown property 'compileJava' for project '' of type org.gradle.api.Project.  - after i deleted this lines it builds. No luck, though, same "??"