# IntelliJ IDEA embeded terminal output encoding issue

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, utf-8, character-encoding

IDEA: IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.3 x64
IDEA Embeded Terminal: `"c:\cygwin64\bin\sh" -lic "cd ${OLDPWD-.}; bash"`

I got **build.gradle**:

```
task info << {
    println "Привет, мир!"
}
```

When i run from embeded terminal `gradle info` i got output:

```
$ gradle info
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

\> Task :info
╨Я╤А╨╕╨▓╨╡╤В, ╨╝╨╕╤А!
```

But if i run `cat ./build.gradle`:

```
$ cat ./build.gradle
task info << {
    println "Привет, мир!"
}
```

I googled that problem and solution with additional Custom VM Options for IDEA not worked

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on where VM options were set actually.

Please call `export GRADLE_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"` before `gradle info` - it should fix it.

---

In case of *Windows Terminal* please use `CP866` encoding instead of `UTF-8` for cyrillic letters, so first command will look like this:

`set GRADLE_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=CP866"`

Comment: Please also find here other approaches on how to set `file.encoding`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267234/show-utf-8-text-properly-in-gradle