# Gradle error: unmappable character (0x8F) for encoding windows-1252

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to build [this library](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-java-sdk) using IntelliJ Idea on Windows 8.

Sadly, while trying to build it I encounter the following error:

```
C:\Users\me\IdeaProjects\vk-java-sdk2\sdk\src\main\java\com\vk\api\sdk\objects\apps\GetPlatform.java:8: error: unmappable character (0x8F) for encoding windows-1252
 * platform. Possible values: *'ios' — iOS,, *'android' — Android,, *'winphone' — Windows Phone,, *'web' — приложени�? на vk.com. By default: 'web'.
                                                                                                                                      ^
```

There are multiple questions with the same problem on SO, but none of them helped me. What I tried so far

- Adding this to `sdk/build.gradle`

```
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
compileTestJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

- Adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to `Help > Edit Custom VM Options...`
- Adding `-encoding utf8 -docencoding utf8 -charset utf8` as additional command line parameters
- Setting `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` as environmental varible
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66420581/4725061)
- Changing file encoding is not an option, I want to contribute to that library.

What else can I do? Thanks.