# Java Gradle Eclipse - UTF-8 symbols showing before build in IDE but not after build

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, gradle, utf-8

i'm fairly new to coding and currently im trying to build my first fat JAR with gradle in eclipse. My project generates a HTML file with data i get from a JSON file. some of the strings in there use UTF-8 symbols/emojis. I managed to get them into my java objects with "Jackson" and by using the getBytes() method for the strings. When i generate the HTML from those objects in eclipse they show up the right way (when opened in browser outside of eclipse).
The problem occurs, when i build the fat jar with "gradlew jar" (i had to make some changes in build.gradle to jar to make it contain the dependencies).
Everything works fine, besides the UTF-8 symbols not showing, instead i get a "?", like the encoding is not set right.
So i think the problem is encoding settings in gradle.

What i tried so far is adding this to gradlew.bat:

```
set GRADLE_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=utf-8
```

this to build.gradle :

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

and  this to gradle.Properties

```
systemProp.file.encoding=utf-8
```

like mentioned in this thread [Show UTF-8 text properly in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267234/show-utf-8-text-properly-in-gradle)

None of those seem to help. Any ideas? Im stuck, struggle to find a solution.

Comment: Do you use `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` also for running your fat JAR? `-Dfile.encoding=...` is the default encoding used at runtime. Don't mix it up with the encoding that is used by the Java compiler to read the .java files ([`javac -encoding ...`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html#standard-options)).

Comment: No, i run it with `java -jar name.jar`

Comment: Thanks, howlger. Running it with `java -jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 name.jar` works.

Comment: Although i dont like that i have to add this to my command. Is there a way to set this inside the project/JAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` sets the **default encoding** used at runtime **when running** your compiled code, e.g. `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar ...`. Don't mix it up with the encoding that is used by the Java compiler to read the `.java` files: `javac -encoding ...`.

To avoid to set it on the command line, you can set it also programmatically via `System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");`. But better set the encoding where it used, e.g. instead of `BufferedWriter writer= Files.newBufferedWriter(path);` `use BufferedWriter writer= Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`.

Comment: Thanks again howlger.  Setting the encoding where the HTML is written helped to avoid the command line addition.
`BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter((new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("test.html"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));`